# CSS Selectors: if div's class name contains AT LEAST one char

Tags: html, css, regex, css-selectors

What is the correct CSS selector if I want to know if there's at least one character in an element's class name?

I use this to know if the div class name inside `.bar` begins with "foo-":

```
.bar div[class^="foo-"] {display: block;}
```

But how do I check if there's just at least one char (letter or number or special char) in the class name?

Comment: CSS doesn't have a wildcard in the attribute selector so I think you'd need JavaScript for that

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check if an element has an empty or missing `class` attribute like this:

```css
div { color: red; } /* has a class attribute with at least one character */
div[class=""] { color: blue; } /* has an empty class attribute */
div:not([class]) { color: green; } /* has no class attribute */
```

```html
<div class="foo">foo</div>
<div class="">bar</div>
<div>baz</div>
```

Comment: This is much better than my first instinct to check every character :P